# Is it been or Has it been?

Tags: grammar

I have sent my expedite request about one month ago, I wanted to make sure:

1- Is it been considered yet?

2- Has it been considered yet?

Comment: 1 - Is it *being* considered yet? 2 - OK.

Comment: @WeatherVane: So both my sentences are incorrect?

Comment: No, **2 - Ok**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Has" is correct. "Is" is third-person present tense form of the verb "Be". "Has" is the third-person present tense form of "Have."

In this case, the subject is "it." You could write "is it being considered?" (continuous tense) or "has it been considered yet?" (perfect tense)